# Discord JDA getOnlineStatus() is not checking for online members on the server

Tags: java, bots, discord, discord-jda

I am trying to make a bot that will list all online members on the discord server using JDA. I have used if(m.getOnlineStatus == OnlineStatus.ONLINE) and this did not work - it didn't include a single username. I have tried using .equals() instead of == but that did not work either. I am using an embed builder and adding the names to the description.

However, it is not .getMembers() that is broken as, if I remove the onlineStatus condition from the if statement, it returns all members of the server as it should do.

Here is my code for this command:

```java
if(event.getMessage().getContentRaw().equalsIgnoreCase("!memberList")) {
    Guild guild = event.getGuild();
    List<Member> users = guild.getMembers();
    int playerCount = guild.getMemberCount();
            
    EmbedBuilder builder = new EmbedBuilder();
        
    builder.setTitle("There " + ((playerCount == 1) ? "is " : "are ") + playerCount + " player" + (playerCount == 1 ? "" : "s") + " online!");
            
    for (Member m : users) {

        if(!m.getUser().isBot() && m.getOnlineStatus() == OnlineStatus.ONLINE) {
            builder.appendDescription(m.getEffectiveName() + "\n");
        }
                
    }
            
    builder.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    builder.setFooter("Requested by " + event.getAuthor().getName());
    event.getChannel().sendMessage(builder.build()).complete();
}
```

My JDABuilder code, JDA 4.2.0:

```
JDA bot;
        
try {
    bot = JDABuilder.createDefault(DISCORD_TOKEN)
            .setChunkingFilter(ChunkingFilter.ALL)
            .addEventListeners(new MessageHandler())
            .setMemberCachePolicy(MemberCachePolicy.ALL)
            .enableIntents(GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS)
            .build();
} catch(LoginException e) {
    System.out.println("Oopsie! Someone did a poopsie!");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Can you include your code for the `JDABuilder` and your version?

Comment: Have added JDABuilder code + Version at the bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable the `GUILD_PRESENCES` intent to keep track of the online status. Add this to your builder: `enableIntents(GatewayIntent.GUILD_PRESENCES)` and enable it in your application dashboard.

Comment: Thanks, it would be good if it told you that that wasn't activated when you tried to use it :/